# Codeigniter ajax pagination not showing links

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I am using this library for my ajax pagination currently. It is working well on another page which is an admin page but on my agent page, it doesn't show any pagination links.
My user has 2 items in the table and i've set the per page to 1 meaning that pagination links should show.
My routes have been set up similar to the Admins route as well. 
Hope someone can take a look and see if I have missed anything?

This is the library I use

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Ajax_pagination{

    var $base_url        = '';
    var $total_rows      = '';
    var $per_page        = 10;
    var $num_links       =  2;
    var $cur_page        =  0;
    var $first_link      = 'First';
    var $next_link       = '&#187;';
    var $prev_link       = '&#171;';
    var $last_link       = 'Last';
    var $uri_segment     = 3;
    var $full_tag_open   = '<ul class="pagination">';
    var $full_tag_close  = '</ul>';
    var $first_tag_open  = '<li>';
    var $first_tag_close = '</li>';
    var $last_tag_open   = '<li>';
    var $last_tag_close  = '<li>';
    var $cur_tag_open    = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    var $cur_tag_close   = '</a></li>';
    var $next_tag_open   = '<li>';
    var $next_tag_close  = '</li>';
    var $prev_tag_open   = '<li>';
    var $prev_tag_close  = '</li>';
    var $num_tag_open    = '<li>';
    var $num_tag_close   = '</li>';
    var $target          = '';
    var $anchor_class    = '';
    var $show_count      = false;
    var $link_func       = 'getData';
    var $loading         = '.loading';

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @access    public
     * @param    array    initialization parameters
     */
    function CI_Pagination($params = array()){
        if (count($params) > 0){
            $this->initialize($params);        
        }
        log_message('debug', "Pagination Class Initialized");
    }

    /**
     * Initialize Preferences
     * @access    public
     * @param    array    initialization parameters
     * @return    void
     */
    function initialize($params = array()){
        if (count($params) > 0){
            foreach ($params as $key => $val){
                if (isset($this->$key)){
                    $this->$key = $val;
                }
            }        
        }

        // Apply class tag using anchor_class variable, if set.
        if ($this->anchor_class != ''){
            $this->anchor_class = 'class="' . $this->anchor_class . '" ';
        }
    }

    function getCurrPage(){
        return $this->cur_page;
    }

    /**
     * Generate the pagination links
     * @access    public
     * @return    string
     */    
    function create_links(){
        // If our item count or per-page total is zero there is no need to continue.
        if ($this->total_rows == 0 OR $this->per_page == 0){
           return '';
        }

        // Calculate the total number of pages
        $num_pages = ceil($this->total_rows / $this->per_page);

        // Is there only one page? Hm... nothing more to do here then.
        if ($num_pages == 1){
//            $info = 'Showing : ' . $this->total_rows;
            $info = '';
            return $info;
        }

        // Determine the current page number.        
        $CI =& get_instance();    
        if ($CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment) != 0){
            $this->cur_page = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);   
            // Prep the current page - no funny business!
            $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
        }

        $this->num_links = (int)$this->num_links;
        if ($this->num_links < 1){
            show_error('Your number of links must be a positive number.');
        }

        if ( ! is_numeric($this->cur_page)){
            $this->cur_page = 0;
        }

        // Is the page number beyond the result range?
        // If so we show the last page
        if ($this->cur_page > $this->total_rows){
            $this->cur_page = ($num_pages - 1) * $this->per_page;
        }

        $uri_page_number = $this->cur_page;
        $this->cur_page = floor(($this->cur_page/$this->per_page) + 1);

        // Calculate the start and end numbers. These determine
        // which number to start and end the digit links with
        $start = (($this->cur_page - $this->num_links) > 0) ? $this->cur_page - ($this->num_links - 1) : 1;
        $end   = (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages) ? $this->cur_page + $this->num_links : $num_pages;

        // Add a trailing slash to the base URL if needed
        $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url, '/') .'/';

        // And here we go...
        $output = '';

        // SHOWING LINKS
        if ($this->show_count){
            $curr_offset = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);
            $info = 'Showing ' . ( $curr_offset + 1 ) . ' to ' ;

            if( ( $curr_offset + $this->per_page ) < ( $this->total_rows -1 ) )
            $info .= $curr_offset + $this->per_page;
            else
            $info .= $this->total_rows;

            $info .= ' of ' . $this->total_rows . ' | ';
            $output .= $info;
        }

        // Render the "First" link
        if  ($this->cur_page > $this->num_links){
            $output .= $this->first_tag_open 
                    . $this->getAJAXlink( '' , $this->first_link)
                    . $this->first_tag_close;
        }

        // Render the "previous" link
        if  ($this->cur_page != 1){
            $i = $uri_page_number - $this->per_page;
            if ($i == 0) $i = '';
            $output .= $this->prev_tag_open 
                    . $this->getAJAXlink( $i, $this->prev_link )
                    . $this->prev_tag_close;
        }

        // Write the digit links
        for ($loop = $start -1; $loop <= $end; $loop++){
            $i = ($loop * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;    
            if ($i >= 0){
                if ($this->cur_page == $loop){
                    $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$loop.$this->cur_tag_close; // Current page
                }else{
                    $n = ($i == 0) ? '' : $i;
                    $output .= $this->num_tag_open
                        . $this->getAJAXlink( $n, $loop )
                        . $this->num_tag_close;
                }
            }
        }

        // Render the "next" link
        if ($this->cur_page < $num_pages){
            $output .= $this->next_tag_open 
                . $this->getAJAXlink( $this->cur_page * $this->per_page , $this->next_link )
                . $this->next_tag_close;
        }

        // Render the "Last" link
        if (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages){
            $i = (($num_pages * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page);
            $output .= $this->last_tag_open . $this->getAJAXlink( $i, $this->last_link ) . $this->last_tag_close;
        }

        // Kill double slashes.  Note: Sometimes we can end up with a double slash
        // in the penultimate link so we'll kill all double slashes.
        $output = preg_replace("#([^:])//+#", "\\1/", $output);

        // Add the wrapper HTML if exists
        $output = $this->full_tag_open.$output.$this->full_tag_close;
        ?>
        <script>
        function getData(page){ 
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('/Common/Check'); ?>",
                success: function(data){
                    if(data==true){
                            $.ajax({
                                method: "POST",
                                url: "<?php echo $this->base_url; ?>"+page,
                                data: { page: page},
                                beforeSend: function(){
                                    $('<?php echo $this->loading; ?>').show();
                                },
                                success: function(data){
                                    $('<?php echo $this->loading; ?>').hide();
                                    $('<?php echo $this->target; ?>').html(data);
                                }
                            });
                    }else{
                        window.location.href="<?php echo site_url('/');?>";
                    }
                }
            });
        }


        </script>
        <?php
        return $output;
    }


    function getAJAXlink($count, $text) {
        $pageCount = $count?$count:0;
        return '<a href="javascript:void(0);"' . $this->anchor_class . ' data-per-page="'.$this->per_page.'" onclick="'.$this->link_func.'('.$pageCount.')">'.$text .'</a>';
    }
}
```

This is the agent index that I use

```
public function index()
    {
        $conditions = array();
        $data = array();
        $data['agent_code'] = $this->AccountModel->get_agent_codes($this->get_id());
        $conditions['agent_code'] = $this->AccountModel->get_agent_codes($this->get_id())[0]->agent_code;
        $conditions['limit'] = $this->get_per_page();
        $totalRec = count($this->DocumentModel->agent_get_and_search($conditions));
        $config['target']      = '#list';
        $config['base_url']    = site_url('/AgentDocuments/Search');
        $config['total_rows']  = $totalRec;
        $config['per_page']    = $this->get_per_page();
        $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['links'] = $this->ajax_pagination->create_links();
        $data['datatable'] = $this->DocumentModel->agent_get_and_search($conditions);
        $data['user'] = $this->AccountModel->get_person($this->get_person_id());
        $data['current_page'] = $this->ajax_pagination->getCurrPage();
        $data['total_rows'] = $config['total_rows'];
        $this->load->view('layout/agents/common/header');
        $this->load->view('layout/agents/common/navigation');
        $this->load->view('layout/agents/common/submenu');
        $this->load->view('layout/agents/common/title',$data);
        $this->load->view('layout/agents/common/errors');
        $this->load->view('agents/documents/index',$data);
        $this->load->view('layout/agents/common/footer');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set **true** for **show_count** in `var $show_count = false;` and also refer following link for pagination.

**https://www.codexworld.com/ajax-pagination-in-codeigniter-framework/**

Comment: Yeah I'm using that site. It works for one section of the site only for some reason

Comment: I enabled var $show_count = true; but nothing happened.

Comment: Did you load ajax_pagination library?

Comment: yeah i did. It is loaded in the construct